# Responsive carrousel with jquery and multiple pages, rows and columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design, carousel

***Mostly looking for a jQuery library doing the following request.***

Here's the deal: I have multiple posts, let's say thirteen to make it easier.

Depending on, either, the window getting resized or the initial display/viewport, I want to have pages and my posts displaying in different view

[Here's example of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc3HX.png)

My code is really simple:

```css
section { font-size: 0; text-align: center; }

section article { display: block; width: 100%; }
section article figure {  }
section article figure img { display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; }
section article .infos {  }
section article .infos p { font-size: 12px; }



@media (min-width: 768px) {
section article { display: inline-block; width: 50%; }
}

@media (min-width: 990px) {
section article { width: 33.333%; }
}


@media (min-width: 1200px) {

}
```

```html
<section>

  <article><figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x240/000/fff/" alt="lorem ipsum dolor" title="lorem ipsum dolor"></figure><div class="infos"><p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div></article>
  <article><figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x240/000/fff/" alt="lorem ipsum dolor" title="lorem ipsum dolor"></figure><div class="infos"><p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div></article>
  <article><figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x240/000/fff/" alt="lorem ipsum dolor" title="lorem ipsum dolor"></figure><div class="infos"><p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div></article>
  <article><figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x240/000/fff/" alt="lorem ipsum dolor" title="lorem ipsum dolor"></figure><div class="infos"><p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div></article>
  <article><figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x240/000/fff/" alt="lorem ipsum dolor" title="lorem ipsum dolor"></figure><div class="infos"><p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div></article>
  <article><figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x240/000/fff/" alt="lorem ipsum dolor" title="lorem ipsum dolor"></figure><div class="infos"><p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div></article>
  <article><figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x240/000/fff/" alt="lorem ipsum dolor" title="lorem ipsum dolor"></figure><div class="infos"><p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div></article>
  <article><figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x240/000/fff/" alt="lorem ipsum dolor" title="lorem ipsum dolor"></figure><div class="infos"><p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div></article>
  <article><figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x240/000/fff/" alt="lorem ipsum dolor" title="lorem ipsum dolor"></figure><div class="infos"><p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div></article>
  <article><figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x240/000/fff/" alt="lorem ipsum dolor" title="lorem ipsum dolor"></figure><div class="infos"><p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div></article>
  <article><figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x240/000/fff/" alt="lorem ipsum dolor" title="lorem ipsum dolor"></figure><div class="infos"><p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div></article>
  <article><figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x240/000/fff/" alt="lorem ipsum dolor" title="lorem ipsum dolor"></figure><div class="infos"><p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div></article>
  <article><figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x240/000/fff/" alt="lorem ipsum dolor" title="lorem ipsum dolor"></figure><div class="infos"><p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div></article>

</section>
```

Any kind of help is welcomed!

Comment: Did you try using slickfy ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), best for each screen, mobile and *really trusted*!

Comment: Slick looks perfect for this, **thanks**. Still dealing with the responsive settings, but this shouldn't take too long understanding the breakpoints options and removing/adding more rows and slidesPerRow.

Comment: for responsive slides you can check "Responsive Display" on the same page and for multiple row you can play with css. at one time you can load 6-8 (as per your requirement) slides. and play with css columns property. you can achieve what you want.